# Show that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\langle Ax,x\rangle - \langle b,x\rangle $ is strictly convex $f(tu + (1-t)v) < tf(u) + (1-t)f(v),\forall t\in(0,1) $

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Show that $f(x)$ is strictly convex, i.e., if $u,v \in R^n$, then $ \forall t\in(0,1)$ this is true:
$$f(tu + (1-t)v) < tf(u) + (1-t)f(v)$$

**Following some reading in the previous related posts:**
[Proof for strongly convex function is strictly convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090991/proof-for-strongly-convex-function-is-strictly-convex)

How can I use the proof (or not use it) and show the above inequality holds where $f$ is $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\langle Ax,x\rangle - \langle b,x\rangle$

Comment: This is obviously not true for any function. What are your assumptions about $f$?

Comment: You mean if $f$ satisfies the defintion in the linked question?
$$\begin{align*}
f(y)\geq f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x),y-x\rangle + \frac{m}{2}\|y-x\|_2^2,
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @AdamLatosiński I'm sorry, I've edited the question.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Sorry for the misunderstaing, I've edited the question with the appropriate $f$, you can also consider it $\phi$

Comment: What is the domain of $x$ and $y$?  $f$ is the solution of the integral solution?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Again my bad, I've edited the question. I already know that $f$ is convex from my previous quesiton: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3198198/if-a-in-rn-times-n-a-0-and-b-in-rn-then-the-function-frac1

Comment: Can you at least show us some effort in solving the problem, say calculating $\nabla f$ that appears in the linked proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is called strictly convex function if $\forall x_1 \neq x_2\in X ,\forall t \in (0,1): f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)<tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2) $

This question was already answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3198240 by Theo Bendit
you only need to do the following modifications,

\begin{align*}
&\lambda\|\sqrt{A} x\|^2 + (1 - \lambda)\|\sqrt{A} y\|^2 - \|\sqrt{A}(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y)\|^2 \\
\ge \; &\lambda\|\sqrt{A} x\|^2 + (1 - \lambda)\|\sqrt{A} y\|^2 - (\lambda\|\sqrt{A} x\| + (1 - \lambda)\|\sqrt{A} y\|)^2 \\
= \; &\lambda(1 - \lambda)(\|\sqrt{A} x\| - \|\sqrt{A} y\|)^2 > 0.
\end{align*}
Since this time $1<\lambda<0$ so it can't be zero, and since $x \neq y$ we get $(\|\sqrt{A} x\| - \|\sqrt{A} y\|) \neq 0$
therefor it is a strictly convex function.